# How to write a linux driver using cmake?

Tags: linux, cmake, kernel, driver

I'm trying [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.0/input/input-programming.html) sample code in VSCode CMake project.

It's giving `error: linux/init.h: No such file or directory` because it requires a Makefile. Is there any way to do it using CMake, so I can just click build and have the module built correctly in VSCode?

Also, where is init.h anyways? I can't find it under /usr/include/linux on ubuntu 23.10, even though I have linux-headers-generic installed.

Answer (score 0):

> where is init.h anyways?

Try running:

```
find /usr -name init.h
```

On my Ubuntu 22.04 machine it's located at `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-91/include/linux/init.h`.

> Is there any way to do it using CMake, so I can just click build and have the module built correctly in VSCode?

I have not done so myself but some quick Googling around suggests it's possible ([example](https://musteresel.github.io/posts/2020/02/cmake-template-linux-kernel-module.html)).